# Download sharepoint file Microsoft Graph from SiteAssets

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a sharepoint with a list of files. I can download it with the id provided by the microsoft graph API without problem. But, I have attached to this file an image to show in my C# application as a thumbnail. This has been created as an image field and, by default, Sharepoint has saved in a different drive(the SiteAssets drive), so, once I try to download it using the id, it says that it can't be found. I have already look for this drive where this image is saved, but it doesn't appear on my companies sharepoint so I can't look for it this way either.

So my question is, is there any way to download this file as a stream to be able to show it?

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to get thumbnail image from SiteAssets with main file id? It shouldn't work, as thumbnail is a separate drive item with its own id.

Try out this approach:

Get your file with data as a list item by adding `expand=listItem` parameter:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{docId}?expand=listItem
```

In response you will have `listItem/fields` object with information for a data column where thumbnail is stored. For example, I have thumbnail stored in custom column named `Pic`, so it contains json string info about image:

```
"listItem":{
    "id":"11012",
    "webUrl":"https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/Shared%20Documents/{foldername}/filename.pdf",
    "createdBy":{},
    "lastModifiedBy":{},
    "parentReference":{},
    "contentType":{},
    "fields@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('{driveId}')/items('{docId}')/listItem/fields/$entity",
    "fields":{
        ...,
        "Pic":"{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fileName\":\"test.jpg\",\"nativeFile\":{},\"fieldName\":\"Pic\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com\",\"fieldId\":\"####\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/{sitename}/SiteAssets/Lists/{listId}/test.jpg\",\"id\":\"{imageId}\"}",
        "id":"11012",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

From that JSON you take value of `serverUrl+serverRelativeUrl` and you should be able to use it in `GET` request to download image as usual file